# Count number from value ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, count, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to add a numbers output from `ng-repeat` ? I have this output from `ng-repeat`

```
1
2
1
```

I want to add that number so it will become 4. this is the code

```
<p data-ng-repeat="ticketA in cart.sw_tickets" ng-if="ticketA.ProductId == tickets.ProductId && ticketA.PricingTypeId == 1" ng-init="adultTOT = ticketA.total_ticket">
     {{adultTOT}}
</p>
```

I'm really new in `Angular` and i'm not really sure I can do trick somewhere inside `ng-repeat`.

hope from anyone help! thanks

Comment: What number do you want to add? It just says "that" number. There are 3 distinct numbers.

Comment: Any luck if you give `ng-init="adultTOT = adultTOT + ticketA.total_ticket"` assuming  `$scope.adultTOT =0` initially

Comment: I want add 1,2,1 from the output, so should display 4

Comment: @Developer I try to change my code

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("SampleController", function($scope) {

    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.adultTOT = 0;
    ctrl.sw_tickets = [{
      Id: 1,
      total_ticket: 1
    }, {
      Id: 2,
      total_ticket: 2
    }, {
      Id: 3,
      total_ticket: 1
    }]
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="app">
  <div data-ng-controller="SampleController as ctrl">
    <p data-ng-repeat="ticketA in ctrl.sw_tickets" ng-init="ctrl.adultTOT=  ctrl.adultTOT+ticketA.total_ticket">
     {{ctrl.adultTOT}}
</p>
  </div>
</div>
```